# How to identify two different erc20 token in solidity contract?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, dapp-development

If I want to develop a dapp, and in that along with ethereum users will have the option of contributing with ERC20 tokens, how can i identify tokens from each other cause as per my understanding anyone can create ERC20 token with same name and symbol, so how to make sure that we are receiving real tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll identify the tokens by their address. Don't worry too much about it if that isn't clear yet; this will be apparent once you start writing code that deals with the tokens.